# TypeScript array.sort() of typed values

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's assume we have a type and an array:

```js
type Fruit = 'apple' | 'orange' | 'pineapple'

const initialFruits: Fruit[] = ['pineapple', 'apple', 'orange']
```

If I try to sort the array before assign the value I get an error:

```js
const initialFruits: Fruit[] = ['pineapple', 'apple', 'orange'].sort()

// Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'Fruit[]'.
```

I found one way to save types after sorting, but it looks weird:

```js
const initialFruits: Fruit[] = [
  'pineapple' as const,
  'apple' as const,
  'orange' as const
].sort()
```

Is there more convenient way to fix that?

Comment: Does `satisfies` as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/W4J5vN) work better for you? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: using as const in this line 
const initialFruits: Fruit[] = ['pineapple', 'apple', 'orange'] as const;

and then sorting may work.

Comment: @jcalz link is not working, posting as an answer will be helpful for everyone.

Comment: type Fruit = 'apple' | 'orange' | 'pineapple'

const initialFruits: Fruit[] = ['pineapple', 'apple', 'orange'] as const

const sortedFruits: Fruit[] = initialFruits.sort();
console.log(sortedFruits)

check this if it works.

Comment: @Adil, not sure why you're having trouble, but the code is just `const initialFruits = (['pineapple', 'apple', 'orange'] satisfies Fruit[]).sort()`. My answers tend to be rather thorough, with links to documentation, so I prefer to wait until I know that it actually addresses the question properly before expending the effort. So until and unless @AlexeyZalyotov replies to me, I'll wait.

Comment: @jcalz could you please explain why your suggestion is better than Adil's one?

Comment: ? You already accepted the other answer so I’m not sure why you want that information.

Comment: @jcalz I cannot accept a comment as an answer if I'm not mistaken. Moreover, I could be wrong and maybe your solution is more correct. I see that you have a lot of experience with TS. I would appreciate it if you write your answer as an answer and explain why your solution is more suitable. I think it's also could be helpful for somebody in the future and it's better to mark as an answer the most correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, I see that @Adil is the one who wrote the answer in question and they already asked me to post my answer, so I'll do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your code to be type safe without changing the runtime behavior (e.g., without calling `sort()` in a separate statement), then my suggestion would be to use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) to give the compiler [context](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) that the [array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals) `['pineapple', 'apple', 'orange']` will be treated as a `Fruit[]`.  Like this:

```
const initialFruits =
    (['pineapple', 'apple', 'orange'] satisfies Fruit[]).sort()
```

That compiles. `['pineapple', 'apple', 'orange'] satisfies Fruit[]` results in an expression of type `("apple" | "orange" | "pineapple")[]` (which is equivalent to `Fruit[]` but wouldn't be if you, for example, wrote `['apple', 'orange'] satisfies Fruit[]`, where you'd get a value of type `("apple" | "orange")[]`).  And so you've still got a mutable array type, which is known to have a `sort()` method. So you get:

```
initialFruits
//^? const initialFruits: ("apple" | "orange" | "pineapple")[]
```

which should work for you.

---

Note that this is a stronger guarantee of type safety than using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) like `as Fruit[]`.  Compare:

```
(['pineapple', 'apple', 'cherry'] satisfies Fruit[]).sort(); // error!
// -------------------> ~~~~~~~~
// Type '"cherry"' is not assignable to type 'Fruit'.

(['pineapple', 'apple', 'cherry'] as Fruit[]).sort(); // no error!
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbCgXigcgIZjAGwkygB8sB7ObAOwHMjSswlqJcCiAoTgY3OoDOqFiiTZ88ZMAHpOUeVAAUAbUzNW7QpgA0WTUV2ZKNepgC6UAdmBIBAMyQQZklMrMBKAHQDKwRe+4RG3EXaQBuTgB6SIA9AH4oPkFhalEQxBQBAC4lACJ9XMZc4zoIQrJc9TY8Qlz3N25OFTUWao4dPRqDLB4ACwg4OBBzS2tbBydYDOA3Lx84P3cwqGioAbhKAEIoyKgAWgPDo+OjgD4oAD8r66udqAAVcGhMXL71kFziWyhqclRsAQCJC0ajYABGhCgwHIUKeWFCmE83GaVX0HRwXXRb0GwwsAKmUlm3l8-mWq1+a0GWyAA)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation of your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Array is sorted according to `Fruit` type.

```
type Fruit = 'apple' | 'orange' | 'pineapple'

const initialFruits: Fruit[] = ['pineapple', 'apple', 'orange'].sort() as Fruit[];

const sortedFruits: Fruit[] = ['pineapple', 'apple', 'orange'].sort((a, b) => {
  return initialFruits.indexOf(a) - initialFruits.indexOf(b);
}) as Fruit[];
```